# Texas excessive fining

Tags: texas, driving, motor-vehicle, fines

I am just curious if it is legal for Texas to issue a ticket, once the ticket is issued you are automatically also required to pay a surcharge to keep your license from being suspended and on top of that you are also required to carry SR-22 insurence for a minimum of 3 years as I understand from the clerk that explained it to me and failure to keep the SR-22 insurence will result in your licences being suspended. How can it be legal to be fined twice and required to obtain special insurance for a minimum of 3 years just for a speeding ticket or some other driving infraction?

Comment: I don't know exactly what happened, but you get those things for some infractions.

Comment: I was accused of speeding said he radared me doing 74 and posted speed was 70

Comment: Did you have a lot of tickets or infractions prior to that though lol. They don't do that when you go 4 over.

Comment: Some but it just happened to my sister also her first ticket ever she has been driving for 11 years and she has to pay the ticket the surcharge and get sr22 insurence. I actually fought a few of the tickets I ha e received over the years and even though I beat the tickets after the courts investigator looked into the matter. My tickets were thrown out but even when that happens you are still required to pay the surcharge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This doesn't remotely approach the threshold to which the excessive fines clause applies. Also SR-22 insurance isn't a fine, it is a requirement that you take extra responsibility because you are a high risk driver.

In general, states have broad authority to regulate the right to drive a car.

Comment: I just cant see how they can get away with this, and of course their is nothing I can do about it. It's a way for them to knock us down and wile we are down they kick us a few time so we cant get back up